# select which is having specific double value

Tags: field-calculator, select-by-attribute, arcgis-10.6

**Title: Trying to Select which is having double space**

I have data like below:

**field name - Address:**

1. Winding Springs Dr
2. Winding Hollow Dr
3. Windsong Ln

in above data i have to select double space values those are like 1 & 2

i'm following:

1. Adding dummy field - coping data into new field
2. Removing spaces in new field
3. Then finding string lengths of new and old field

finally which is having two or more length differ then that is my output

It is too lengthy a process so can you advise a better solution?

Comment: Please [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/350544/edit) your question (don't add as a comment) to include what software you use.

Comment: In python I would split the string by spaces and get the len of the list, for example len(!Address!.split(' ')) > 2 where !Address! is the field in ArcGIS field calculator syntax. Depending on your underlying data storage and nominated software https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21454684/count-the-number-of-spaces-in-values-in-sql-server might help

Answer (score 2):

Use this SQL statement in the Select By Attributes window:

```
Address LIKE '% % %'
```

`%` is a wildcard that means ‘0 or more characters’. Note that there are spaces between the `%` signs.

Comment: Thank you @Berend